# Why is Await not working in async function?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am trying to use await in an async function. Hwoever, I am getting the error

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

I cant figure out where the problem is in the below code.

```
insertPayrollAllowance: async function(companyId, jobId, basicSalary, employeeId, payrollId) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            sqlQuery = "SELECT * from tblJobAllowances Where tblJobAllowances.companyId = '" + companyId + "' and tblJobAllowances.jobId = '" + jobId + "' and deleterec = 0 order by id"
            db.executeQuery(sqlQuery, null, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {

                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                        var insStatus = false;
                        var allowanceId = result[i].allowanceId
                        var allowanceName = await this.getAllowanceName(companyId, allowanceId);
                        var amountType = result[i].typeOfAmount;
                        var amount = result[i].amount;
                        var amountCredited;
                        var taxable = result[i].taxable;

                        if ($.trim(amountType) == "FIXED AMT") {

                            amountCredited = parseFloat(amount.toString().replace(/,/g, ''));


                        } else if ($.trim(amountType) == "% Of Income") {

                            amountCredited = (parseFloat(basicSalary.toString().replace(/,/g, '')) / 100) * parseFloat(amount.toString().replace(/,/g, ''));

                        };

                        var info = {
                            companyId: companyId,
                            employeeId: employeeId,
                            payrollId: payrollId,
                            allowanceName: allowanceName,
                            amountType: amountType,
                            amount: amount,
                            amountCredited: amountCredited,
                            taxable: taxable
                        }

                        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tblPayrollAllowanceDetails SET ?"
                        db.executeQuery(sqlQuery, info, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                insStatus = false;
                            } else {
                                insStatus = true;
                            }
                        });

                    };

                    resolve(insStatus);

                }
            });
        });

    }
```

I will be glad if anyone could point out why Im getting this error. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Because you're **not** in an async function. You're in the `Promise` callback. But there's really no point making a function `async` if the first thing it does is `return new Promise(...)`.

Comment: The anonymous function `db.executeQuery(sqlQuery, null, (err, result) => {` is not async. Change it to `db.executeQuery(sqlQuery, null, async (err, result) => {`

Comment: Do not EVER mix plain callbacks with promises or `async/await`.  You will not be able to control the flow of execution because the plain callbacks don't respect the promise flow or the error propagation.  If you want to use promises, then use ONLY promise interfaces for all your asynchronous operations in this function.  If this is mySql, you can get a version of it that supports promises for all database operations.  Then, you can properly control everything with `async/await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The await is inside another function that's not async

```
 db.executeQuery(sqlQuery, null, (err, result) => {
```

It's inside this arrow function (err, result) => {
so to fix it just add async like so:

```
db.executeQuery(sqlQuery, null, async (err, result) => {
```